# Create a custom property

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am looking for a way to create a custom property in access with VBA.

Here's how far I am and where I am stuck:

A custom property's value (whose name is **foo**) can be read like so:

```
Dim cnt As Container
Dim doc As Document

Set cnt = DBEngine(0)(0).Containers!Databases
Set doc = cnt.Documents!userDefined

doc.Properties.Refresh
Debug.Print (doc.Properties!foo)
```

Similary, I can create a new property:

```
doc.Properties.Append doc.CreateProperty("vba created", dbText, "yes")
```

Now, the problem is:

```
Set doc = cnt.Documents!userDefined
```

does only work when I have already at least one custom property in the mdb. So, in order to create a custom property with VBA, I need to create a custom property.

I don't want to create this custom property manually (which would work) because I need
to create a few MDBs with VBA and would like to do everything without manual intervention.

Thanks for any pointer to the right direction

Rene

**EDIT for clarity**

Here's a (trimmed down) code that I hope can be used to demonstrate what I cannot accomplish:

```
option explicit

public sub add_user_defined_property ()

on error goto error_lbl

  dim ac  as access.application
  dim cnt as dao.container
  dim doc as dao.document
  dim prp as dao.property
  dim db  as dao.database

  dim mdb_name as string
      mdb_name = "c:\temp\cust_prop_test.mdb"

  set ac = new access.application
  set db = ac.dbEngine.workspaces(0).createDatabase(mdb_name, dbLangGeneral, 0)

  ac.openCurrentDatabase(mdb_name)

' set cnt = DBEngine(0)(0).Containers("Databases")
  set cnt = db.containers("Databases")

  ' following line throws "3265 Item not found in this collection"
  set doc = cnt.Documents!UserDefined

  set prp = doc.createProperty("MyNewProperty", dbText, "MyNewProperty")
  doc.properties.append prp

' for Each prp In doc.Properties
'     debug.print "Name = " & prp.Name & ", value = " & prp.Value
' next

error_lbl:

  select case err.number
         case 3265
              msgBox("Expected error occured")
         case else
              msgBox(err.number & vbCrLf & err.description)
  end select

end sub
```

This code throws the 3265 (Item not found in this collection) error at the line reading

```
  set doc = cnt.Documents!UserDefined
```

because (as I think) the mdb is newly created and does not yet contain the *userDefined* member in cnt.Documents. It would work, if I had already manually added such a property, that is, by opening the mdb file with access, then going to menu File->Database Properties then going to the custom tab.

Comment: You must be creating these MDBs in code, as any MDB created with Access has a UserDefined properties collection with several properties in it. Why not just trap for the error and ignore it?

Comment: I don't see how ignoring the error would help.

Comment: Well, by "ignore" I mean that you trap for the error caused by the lack of a UserDefined document and proceed with whatever it is you want to do in its absence (e.g., create the UserDefined document and add some properties to it, or whatever it is you want to do).

Comment: Yes, that would probably work, if only I could add this UserDefined document. But since this doesn't seem to work I am stuck.

Comment: You can't use what doesn't exist, so you have to add it to the Database.Documents collection (I think -- I don't know, as I've not got any MDBs that weren't created in Access).

Comment: @Rene Nyffenegger I created a database with ADO and it was indeed missing UserDefined. Is it possible for you to create the database according to the notes here: http://www.4tops.com/ms_access_tips/usdefprp.htm ?

Comment: Remou, that link certainly helped me. In fact, I'd like to accept it as answer, but I can't since you've posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using createdatabase to create the DB file.  Creating the MDB file this way only creates the MSysDB document object.

To create the database as you are trying to do and be able to set a property in the documents!userdefined object, you must create the database from the application.

To do this, change these lines:

```
  set ac = new access.application
  set db = ac.dbEngine.workspaces(0).createDatabase(mdb_name, dbLangGeneral, 0)

  ac.openCurrentDatabase(mdb_name)
```

to:

```
  set ac = new access.application
  ac.NewCurrentDatabase (mdb_name)

  Set db = ac.CurrentDb
```

This will create a .mdb file and it will have 3 documents in it named MSysDb, SummaryInfo and UserDefined.

Your code helped me solve the problem I was working on, hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT re Comment

```
Set cnt = DBEngine(0)(0).Containers("Databases")
Set doc = cnt.Documents!UserDefined

Set prp = doc.CreateProperty("MyNewProperty", dbText, "MyNewProperty")
doc.Properties.Append prp

For Each prp In doc.Properties
    Debug.Print "Name = " & prp.Name & ", value = " & prp.Value
Next
```

Here is some sample code from [`Less Than Dot`](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Custom_Database_Properties_Creation_and_Use), where you will find more details.

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : CreateDBStrProp
' Purpose   : Create a Custom Database Property of dbText (string) type
' Arguments : strPropName As String-the Property Name
'           : strPropValue As String-the Property Value
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Function CreateDBStrProp(strPropName As String, strPropValue As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Err_CreateDBStrProp

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim prp As Property

    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)

    '' First we verify the Property Exists to avoid an error
    If ExistsDBProperty(strPropName) = False Then
        Set prp = db.CreateProperty(strPropName, dbText, strPropValue)
        db.Properties.Append prp
    Else
        Set prp = db.Properties(strPropName)
        prp.Value = strPropValue
        MsgBox "DBProperty " & strPropName & " already exists.        " _
            & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Property value was set." _
            , vbExclamation
    End If

    CreateDBStrProp = True

Exit_CreateDBStrProp:
    Set prp = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_CreateDBStrProp:
    CreateDBStrProp = False
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ")" & _
    " In procedure CreateDBStrProp"
    Resume Exit_CreateDBStrProp
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this is not whaty I want. The properties I want to create are under 
DBEngine(0)(0).Containers!Databases.Documents!userDefined.Properties, not under DBEngine(0)(0).Properties.
These Properties (those under ...!userDefined) can be seen with Menu File -> Database Properties -> Custom

Comment: I thought the problem was that the UserDefined document does not exist, not that it contained no properties?

Comment: The original question has been considerably edited since this post. However, I feel this post stands as contributing to the edits.

Comment: Even in 2023, Access continues to be the oddball of Office products. Why are custom document properties in such a weird place? The world may never know.